# rails : whitelisting multiple object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a form for order that containing products(id,quantity) that are added dynamically 
form:
    <%= form_for(order) do |f| %>

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :note %>
    <%= f.text_field :note %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <% Product.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}.each do |c| -%>
        <%= label_tag(name=c.first) %>
        <%= number_field_tag( 'products[][:qty]','',min:1) %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag( 'products[][:id]',c.last) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the received params looks like this:

```
{"order"=>{"note"=>"mm","user_id"=>"mm"}, "products"=>[{":qty"=>"2",":id"=>"1"}, {":qty"=>"2", ":id"=>"2"}]}
```

How to permit these parameters 
I tried this but did not work:

```
params.require(:order).permit(:note)
params.permit(:products => [])
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nicer to redo your form so it inclueds products in the order where they logically belong (excercise left to reader) and return params like

```ruby
{"order"=>{"note"=>"mm","user_id"=>"mm", "products"=>[{":qty"=>"2",":id"=>"1"}, {":qty"=>"2", ":id"=>"2"}]}}
```

Than you can easily do this

```ruby
order_params = params.require(:order).permit(:note, :products => [:qty, :id])
```

and for convenience you may extract products like this (but this is not needed)

```ruby
products_params = params.delete("products")
```